# Display blob image from database into jlabel

Tags: java, mysql, blob, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

```
public void displayPhoto() {

    rs = null;
    String displaySQL = "select * from images where USERNAME ='" + temp.getUsername() + "'";
    try {

        con = getDBConnection();
        rs = st.executeQuery(displaySQL);
        while (rs.next()) {
            BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGES"));
            displayPhoto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I'm trying to display the image from database, the image stored as longblob. it says          NULLPOINTERS, I dunno what's the problem

the table has 2 columns(USERNAME,IMAGES)
images = table name,
IMAGES = Column name,
`displayPhoto = JLabel`

can anyone help me?
thanks in advance<3

Here is the full error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:228)
at MyProfile.displayPhoto(MyProfile.java:395)
at MyProfile.<init>(MyProfile.java:195)
at Login.actionPerformed(Login.java:93)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Could you give more details as to what part is giving you a `NullPointerException`? Is it the ImageIO.read?

Comment: Is your `IMAGES` column defined to be `not null`? Otherwise, you should test for `null` before attempting read. Also, you should test that `im` is not `null` before attempting to display, as `ImageIO` can't magically turn any kind of blob into a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: I edited the post, i included the error message. the IMAGES column defined to be not null, then data type is longblob

Comment: What problem do you want solved? The `NullPoniterException` to go away, or understanding why ImageIO can't read the data in your blob? The first is trivial, and not suited for SO. The second needs more input on your part (ie, what is the contents of your blob when you encounter an NPE?).

Comment: How to read the data(image) in my blob and display it into jlabel

Answer (score 2):

```
   try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login", "root", "obierofelix");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from images");
            rs.next();
            BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(rs.getBinaryStream("Image"));
            BackGroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im));
        } catch (Exception err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply rs.next(); before the try and catch block to move the pointer to the first record in the database.